# How to add cocoa pods to this project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I got an error after installing this [pod](https://github.com/Loadex/MessageBanner). 
I successfully got that original app to work after bringing it to my desktop and installing pods.

The problem is that after trying it with the real app I want to merge it with, after running pod install and opening the .xcodeworkspace project; I get 1 warning saying the file is already open or something like that.

My question: Should one run `pod install` in the same place where my original .xcodeproj is located or somewhere else? How do I install this pod to my own application without an error? When I open workspace I see the title of my app and under it 4 pods with a question mark and one compiler warning.

```
WTL2:~ Apple$ cd desktop
WTL2:desktop Apple$ cd myapp
WTL2:myapp Apple$ touch podfile
WTL2:myapp Apple$ open -a TextEdit Podfile
WTL2:myapp Apple$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.36.0.beta.2 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Downloading dependencies
Installing FXBlurView (1.6.3)
Installing HexColors (2.2.1)
Installing MessageBanner (1.0.3)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] From now on use `myapp.xcworkspace`.
WTL2:faunna Apple$
```

The specific Xcode warning is:

`couldn't load myapp because it is already open from another project or workspace`

Comment: Yes, same place the .xcodeproj is located. After that don't use the .xcodeproj file, use the .xcodeworkspace - this will have the original project, along with the 'Pods' project that compiles and links the libs.

Comment: sounds good. Either way whats your take on the warning? I'll try restarting my machine. see you soon

Comment: [This one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2)  will resolve all your queries regarding cocoa pods

Comment: good tutorial. I just restarted my computer and am still getting the warning saying myapp.xcodeproj couldn't load because its already open from another project or workspace. This is weird because I just restarted my machine. what do i do?

Comment: ill give it another read...

Comment: funny...i just closed Xcode again and now it works. yay. every time I've had a cocoa pods issue to troubleshoot I simply tried again a few dozen times till it works...